# Manipulate image without saving it

Tags: php, image-uploading

I want to do things on an image uploaded by the user.

Until now, what I do is:

1. `move_uploaded_file`
2. `imagecreatefrompng`

How can I manipulate it without saving it?

Comment: Just do the manipulations and don't call `imagejpg()` et al. in the end. I have an inkling that your question is about something else though...

Comment: @Pekka Manipulations on which variable?

Comment: the one you get from `imagecreatefrompng`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the file is uploaded, it has to be stored somewhere in the server's `/tmp/` folder. Simply load your image from there using `$_FILES['name']['tmp_name']`.

For example:

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['blarg']['tmp_name']);
```

Will load the uploaded file (called `blarg`) from it's temporary storage place under something like `/tmp/php-12bja`. You don't need to call `move_uploaded_file()`, and the image doesn't need to be saved to disk.

Comment: `imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['name']['tmp_name']);` ?

Comment: /tmp isn't stored at RAM by default. It's getting cleaned by rebooting server.

Comment: `/tmp` usually isn't a ramdrive.